# Titanium accounts, costs and releasing an app

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, account

This is my very first post in Stackoverflow, but I've found this site very useful.

Here is my first question.
I've been searching the web for an answer for a while now. I've contacted Titanium and no luck.

Why should users have an account with Titanium?
Do you have to buy another account than "FREE" to be able to use full Titanium functionality?
Do you have to buy an account to be able to release your app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Titanium framework is free and open source. You do not need to be a premium user to build apps with the Titanium framework and/or distribute the apps.

The only reason you may want to be a Titanium premium user is for dedicated support and the Ti+ Modules. There is a forum where you can get support and of course stackoverflow (all for free)! The Ti+ modules extend the core functionality of Titanium with for example in-app payments. You can of course write your own module if you know a little Objective-C to get around this.

Bottom line is, i've found it more than superb for building a large majority of apps I've had to build and i'm not a premium user. The documentation is sound. And for in-app payments I've rolled my own module, which I am going to open source in the next few weeks.

Comment: Thank you @Brian Huenefeld and @Gcoop for the clear info.

Comment: No, titanium cli ask for registration when build distribution build. I had tried "appc ti build -p android -T dist-playstore" then it ask for registration.

Answer (score 0):

Leon from what I've been told a Titanium account is for fast support. A recent [tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/appcelerator/status/69105182507667456) from the team suggest they are not getting the number of sales they'd like due to current high pricing. I haven't personally distributed an app but I can't imagine an account would be required especially since you can build for the device straight from xCode or command line if needed using the `build/` folder. I'm sure some other people here will have some better advice then me in this category but I hope this helps.